# Laravel database problem - Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: mysql, centos, upgrade, mysql.sock

Yesterday I tried to update MySQL version on Centos 6 from 5.5 to 10.2 because Server said 5.5 was no longer supported

After that, I can not connect to the MySQL database and all my Laravel project are down.

I got an error:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Too many
>   levels of symbolic links

also this is what I got in WHM:

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I'm not really a server guy.

Also this is when I check boxes and continue with upgrading:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by update `DB_SOCKET` value in **database.php** or **env file**.

```
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/mamp/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

I hope this will be okay.